# Aurelia router.navigate not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, aurelia

I'm trying to reroute my customers to the login page on logout and take their current page path out of their address bar, so if they log back in, they will be taken to their default start page and not their last visited page.

Here is my rerouting code.

```
this.router.navigate('#/', { replace: true, trigger: false });
this.aurelia.setRoot('components/pages/login/login');
```

This is working as expected in IE, but Chrome redirects with the previous route still in the address bar.  Why?

And yes, before you ask, I have tried replacing this.router.navigate with `this.router.redirectToRoute('#/');` with no luck.

Comment: It is also not working in the latest Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that this.router.navigate was failing to reroute because I was accessing it via an eventAggregator.subscribe event.  I moved the navigate to the reload method that fires after the subscription function, and voila.  Goofy.